# eslint: "Parsing error: Unexpected token of"

Tags: javascript, eslint

When using the following code in my web app I get the following return from ESLint. I would prefer using this loop method as opposed to the increment I method. What does this error mean? And does it mean there is something wrong with the use of the loop?

Error Message:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token of
```

Actual effected code:

```
renderCanvas: function() {
  console.log("Rendering Model");
  var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName("DesignerCanvas");
  for (var canvas of canvases) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    // String for Hanging
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    // Top Trimming
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    // Outter Shade Body
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    // Bottom Trimming
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    // Inner Shade Body
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like ESLint doesn't understand `for..of` because it si complaining about the token `of`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for-of` loops are an EcmaScript 6 feature, and these are not enabled by default in ESLint.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/eslint/eslint#what-about-ecmascript-6-support):

> **What about ECMAScript 6 support?**
>   ESLint has full support for ECMAScript 6. By default, this support is off. You can enable ECMAScript 6 support through [configuration](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

If you then follow the configuration link, it tells you that you can enable the `es6` environment with

```
/*eslint-env es6 */
```

in the JavaScript file, or

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

in the configuration file.